# SWIProlog C# System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, exception, prolog, swi-prolog

please help me because I'm desperate because I don't understand why my method doesn't work.

I have this:

```
public static List<int> caminhoMaisCurto(int iduser1, int iduser2)
        {
            List<int> ret = new List<int>();

            using (PlQuery q = new PlQuery("mais_curto(" + iduser1 + "," + iduser2 + ",C)."))
            {
                PlTermV v = q.Solutions.First();

                IReadOnlyCollection<PlTerm> lista = v[2].ToList();

                foreach(var row in lista)
                {
                    int num = Convert.ToInt32(row.ToString());
                    ret.Add(num);
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }
```

It belongs to a webservice that communicates with a .pl file with prolog.

It initiates like this:

```
public static void init()
        {
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("SWI_HOME_DIR", @"C:\Users\João\Desktop\SWI-PrologPortable\App\SWI-Prolog");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", @"C:\Users\João\Desktop\SWI-PrologPortable\App\SWI-Prolog");
            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", @"C:\Users\João\Desktop\SWI-PrologPortable\App\SWI-Prolog\\bin");
            if (!PlEngine.IsInitialized)
            {
                String[] param = { "-q", "-s", "C:\\Users\\João\\final\\lapr5-dei-link\\DAL_BLL\\AIWebService\\AIWebService\\AI.pl" };  // suppressing informational and banner messages
                PlEngine.Initialize(param);               
            }
        }
```

and it gives the `System.AccessviolationException` in this line:

```
using (PlQuery q = new PlQuery("mais_curto(" + iduser1 + "," + iduser2 + ",C)."))
```

I dont' understand why... Can someone help?

Comment: if there is a PlFrame class available in C# interface you are using, try `using (new PlFrame) {}`

Comment: I've added that and sometimes it breaks with the same exception in the PlFrame line and others it breaks in q.solutions.first()

Comment: you should put inside brackets your code using PlQuery. Did you ?

Comment: yes i did. I put all my code inside the brackets of the PlFrame

Comment: could it have something to do with the location of the file? I have my .pl file in the same folder as the webservice project